# Script to alert a resize is necessary for database to fit into memory?

Tags: database, bash, postgresql, ram

I want to create a bash script that will alert me that the size of my database is becoming too large to fit into memory. An effective bash script would run daily and only alert me via email when `db_size / memory >= 0.5`.

For example: `You should to size up your Digital Ocean Droplet soon for your PostgreSQL server: db_size = 0.6 GB; system_memory = 1.0 GB;`

The problem is I am not sure exactly how to accurately make this comparison. My first stab at this was to use psql command `pg_size_pretty` and the Linux command `free.` Is there a good/accurate comparison that I can make between db_size and total memory size (or another field) to alert me when I need to resize my droplet? Or are there any tools already in place that do this type of thing?

#### Bash Script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
db_size=`psql dbname username -c "SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size('dbname') );"`
echo $db_size

free
```

#### Output

```
user@postgres-server:~/gitrepo/scripts/cronjobs# bash postgres_db_size_check.sh 
pg_size_pretty ---------------- 6976 kB (1 row)
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        1016000       48648      142404       54492      824948      699852
Swap:             0           0           0
```

**What is the correct comparison to use in the output above?** In the output above the size of the PostgreSQL DB is only 6.976 MB and the server's available memory is 1,016.00 MB. So right now we are at 0.6% of RAM used (6.976 / 1,016.00) with < 20 users. As I scale my database I expect the size of the database to increase quickly and I want to stay ahead of it before RAM becomes an issue.

After doing some digging into [PostgreSQL tuning](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server) I have gathered that giving PostgreSQL more memory to use is not as straightforward as just increasing the amount of RAM. Several variables likely need to be set to use the additional memory including work_mem, effective_cache_size, and shared_buffers. I say this to note that I realize increasing the size of my server's RAM is only one step in the process.

I asked [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/240651/script-to-alert-me-that-a-droplet-resize-is-necessary-for-postgresql-db-to-fit-i) on Database Administrators but no one got back to me over there.

Comment: why you want all the db in memory?

Comment: speed mostly https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18484/tuning-postgresql-for-large-amounts-of-ram

Comment: What slowdown are you seeing when the database size is 60% the size of system RAM? 120%? What workloads are you seeing that slowdown with?

Comment: @jmelesky. Nothing yet. It is currently less than 1% of total RAM but I'm about to open up my application (ungate it). Are you suggesting this is not a useful check? Or does it depend on the type of application?

Comment: Well, you know what they say about "premature optimization". Basically, lots of ways we can help make something faster, but most won't recommend "ensure the whole DB is in RAM" as the first step.

Comment: Fair enough. But what's the alternative? 3rd party monitoring? How can I answer the question: "When do I need to resize my server" for a database server?

Comment: The answer is "when things slow down too much", where the definition of "too much" varies. And the solution might not be more RAM -- your active set may still be small. Instead you might need an index, or a schema refactor, or some config tuning, or more cores, or whatever.